# How do I change the color of the menu bar in terminal Emacs?

Tags: terminal-emacs, colors, menu-bar

I am using Emacs in a terminal. This is what the menu bar looks like:

[image: Emacs menu-bar-mode]

The menu bar has a white foreground and a black background. I want a green background with a pink foreground instead. Is there a way to do this?

(Emacs version: GNU Emacs 25.2.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a green background and a bold pink foreground for the menu bar, add this to your Emacs configuration:

```lisp
(set-face-attribute 'menu nil
                    :inverse-video nil
                    :background "green"
                    :foreground "pink"
                    :bold t)
```

Result:

[image: Emacs menu bar]

Answer (score 1):

Fonts and colors are assigned to faces, and faces are assigned to text in both the buffers and the UI. The text in the menu and menu popups uses the `menu` face, so if you run `M-x customize-face RET menu RET` you'll be able to change it to look how you want.